# How to filter products in woocommerce based on some parameters...endpoints required

Tags: android, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to apply filters while fetching products from my woocommerce inventory for my android app. For fetching the products based on categories I am using the URL

mysite/wc-api/v3/products?filter[category]="+mycategory".

This is working fine and I am getting the required results.

Now I need to fetch the products based on some filters such as price, brand etc.

I tried using

1> mysite/wc-api/v3/products?filter[category]="+category+"?filter[price]="+price+"" and

2> mysite/wc-api/v3/products?filter[category]="+category+"&filter[price]="+price+"".

Its not working.

Comment: I am referrering http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#parameters

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure about the answer. But, I am sure that this can not solve the problem. Here is my code:

```
Woocommerce.get('products?filter[category]='+$stateParams.categoryID && 'products?filter[category]='+filter[offset], function(err, data, res){
```

Comment: *"I am sure that this can not solve the problem"*? So you're sure that this answer is wrong?